# How to properly split a RowLayout into two equal fields in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Here is a simple example:

```
RowLayout {
   spacing: 5

   ColumnLayout {
      Text {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         text: qsTr("Some text")
      }
      Rectangle {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         height: 100
         color: "red"
      }
   }

   ColumnLayout {
      Text {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         text: qsTr("Some more text")
      }
      Rectangle {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         height: 50
         color: "red"
      }
   }
}
```

This will produce two equal fields in `width` of the `RowLayout`, but why do I have to specify `Layout.fillWidth: true` for all of the children?

Here is the same example by removing `Layout.fillWidth: true` from the `Text` components:

```
RowLayout {
   spacing: 5

   ColumnLayout {
      Text {
         text: qsTr("Some text")
      }
      Rectangle {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         height: 100
         color: "red"
      }
   }

   ColumnLayout {
      Text {
         text: qsTr("Some more text")
      }
      Rectangle {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         height: 50
         color: "red"
      }
   }
}
```

Here the two fields of the `RowLayout` won't be same in `width`.

Comment: Neither code sample produces two fields that are equal in width; the first Rectangle is always narrower than the second under Qt 5.6, which was available when posted, and Qt 5.15, the last Qt 5 version.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Layout.preferredWidth` to set size of row's element (absolute or relative):

```js
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 0
    Rectangle {
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "green"
    }
    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "yellow"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But what if I have spacing set to a number other than 0 or I want 3 equal fields? Setting parent.width / 2 or 3 and so on + adding the value of spacing into the equation manually feels a bit hacky.

Comment: Ok, let say you have `RowLayout` 100px and you want to split it to 3 equal areas. what width in pixels will you set for each one? As you see I didn't set width fol the last `Rectangle` so it will fill all the remaining space, without spacing etc.

Comment: +0: This splits the entire window into two rectangles; it is not what the original poster requested.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use a GridLayout with two columns.

```
Rectangle {
    height: 20
    width: 300
    color: "green"
    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "blue"
        }
    } //GridLayout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RowLayout` will not size its children equally if they are not the same width.

You can get what you want if you specify the same `Layout.preferredWidth` for each child item of the `RowLayout`.

The code below uses an invisible column to determine the maximum Text width, then sets the `Layout.preferredWidth` for each child `ColumnLayout` element:

[image: Output from code sample with two fields that are same width]

```
Column {
    id: sizer
    visible: false
    Text { text: text1.text }
    Text { text: text2.text }
}

RowLayout {
    spacing: 5

    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.preferredWidth: sizer.width
        Text {
            id: text1
            text: qsTr("Some text")
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 100
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.preferredWidth: sizer.width
        Text {
            id: text2
            text: qsTr("Some more text")
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 50
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```